# Android Language

Tags: android, localization

I am training to force my application to start in Arabic.
so I set my class **LocalHelper**.

```
object LocalHelper {

    fun onAttach(context: Context): Context {
        val lang = getPersistedData(context/*, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()*/)
        return setLocale(context, lang)
    }

    private fun setLocale(context: Context, language: String): Context {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            updateResources(context, language)
        } else updateResourcesLegacy(context, language)

    }

    private fun getPersistedData(context: Context): String {
//        val appComponent = Injector.INSTANCE.appComponent
//            ?: return SharedPreferencesUtils(context, DATABASE_NAME_QURAN, Gson())
//                .currentLanguage.id
        return Language.ARABIC
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private fun updateResources(context: Context, language: String): Context {
        val locale = Locale(language)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)

        val configuration = context.resources.configuration
        configuration.setLocale(locale)
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
    }

    private fun updateResourcesLegacy(context: Context, language: String): Context {
        val locale = Locale(language)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)

        val resources = context.resources

        val configuration = resources.configuration
        configuration.locale = locale
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)
        }

        context.resources.configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)

        return context
    }

}
```

- And in My **Application** class, I update my configuration and base Attach.

```
    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        LocalHelper.onAttach(context = this)
    }

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(
            LocalHelper.onAttach(
                context = base
            )
        )
    }
```

- Also, I create **Strings.xml** for Arabic.
- Finally i update my **BaseActivity** configuration and attach such as Application class.
- When i run my application direction is correct but text is still English

So it work fine from android 8, but in android 7,6 or 5 it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after AndroidX migrate.

It is a bug on androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity extending FragmentActivity or Activity instead of AppCompatActivity will fix the issue. It's not the best option but I'm not finding a workaround for this.